# WPF draw text in ModelVisual3D

Tags: wpf, text, 3d

I'm creating WPF application in which I'm drawing a point cloud. Points are made as little cubes. I'd like to sign indexes with numbers near to each "cube-point" (eg. 1, 2, 3, ...) so I want to add text to my 3D View.

This is my xaml part:

```
       <ModelVisual3D x:Name="model">
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <Model3DGroup x:Name="group">
                    <AmbientLight Color="DarkGray" />
                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="-5,-5,-7" />
                </Model3DGroup>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
```

In code-behind I'm adding GeometryModel3D (built with mesh cube-points) to Model3DGroup (named 'group').

I tried to use this code: http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/4_Text.html
but this is very inefficient way and everything works slowly when I generate and display about 7000 (number of cube-points) such textBlocks.

Do you have any idea how to add some text in a more efficient way?

Answer (score -1):

Of course!
The best resouces about majority of WPF 3D features are in
1. Petzold Ch. book: 3D Programming for Windows
2. Jack Xu. Practical WPF Graphics Programming

Simplest way to take WPF 3D text feature is to work with code from the first detected book
http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/companion/9780735623941/